# Dealing with huge data

Tags: performance, haskell

Let's assume that I have a big file (500GB+) and I have a data record
declaration `Sample` which indicates a row in that file:

```
data Sample = Sample {
field1 :: Int,
field2 :: Int
}
```

Now what is the data structure suitable for processing
(filter/map/fold) on the collection of these `Sample` datas ? Don
Stewart [has answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1925812/1651941) that the `Sample` type should not be treated
as a list `[Sample]` type but as a `Vector` type. My question is how
does representing it as `Vector` type solve the problem ? Doesn't
representing the file contents as a vector of `Sample` type will also
occupy around 500Gb ?

What is the recommended method for solving these types of problem ?

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. How to structure data? or how to locate a data record? Is it not fast enough? takes too much space? Also, can't you just ask Jon to elaborate on his answer?

Comment: I think the comments from 2009 remain. Don't store it as a list in memory, process incrementally using laziness and/or mmap.

Comment: @DonStewart Thanks, but how does treating them as `Vector` solves this problem ? If I have to do two or more `map` operations on the entire Vector data of `Sample`, doesn't it exhaust out the memory ?

Comment: You can't hold all the data in memory no matter what you do. Vector simply increases the amount you can process in each chunk. You must still use laziness or explicit laziness via mmmap to process incrementally.

Comment: @DonStewart Thanks, can you put up that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, the operations you want to use (`filter`, `map` and `fold`) can be done via both conduit (see [`Data.Conduit.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.1.6/docs/Data-Conduit-List.html)) and pipes (see [`Pipes.Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html)).

Both libraries are perfectly capable of manipulating/folding and filtering *streaming* data. Depending on your scenario they might solve your actual problem.

If you, however, need to investigate values several times, you're better of by loading chunks into a vector, as [@Don](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83805/don-stewart) said.

Comment: Thanks, Is `Data.Conduit.List` reasonable for this ? As soon as I build up the list to pass it to `sourceList`, my memory will explode.

Comment: You cannot build up the source list—you have to generate the data incrementally and feed it directly into the conduit.

Comment: @Sibi You need to use `sourceFile` from `Data.Conduit.Binary`.